# Query insists on quoted columns

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate

I have a local copy of Postgres running, and I'm working on a C# .Net Core 2.1 app using nHibernate as an ORM.

It's started throwing an exception: `PostgresException: 42703: column this_.datasetname does not exist`

When I copy the SQL and run in pgAdmin I get a similar error.

This is a short version of the SQL which gives the same error:

```
SELECT this_.datasetName FROM orders this_
```

> ERROR:  column this_.datasetname does not exist LINE 1: SELECT
>   this_.datasetName FROM orders this_
>                  ^ HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "this_.datasetName". SQL state: 42703 Character: 8

If I add quotes around the column name (but not around `_this.` as suggested) it works, but obviously I can't tell nHibernate to do that.

```
SELECT this_."datasetName" FROM orders this_
```

The following also works fine:

```
SELECT "datasetName" FROM orders
```

Why would it insist on adding the quotes? It never used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because this column was created with the surrounding double quotes in the first place - this makes the identifier case-sensitive, while by default it isn't. Since the identifier contains mixed case, you are stucked: the identifier needs to be quoted everywhere you use it.

If you look at the definition of the table, you will see something like:

```
create table orders (
    ...,
    "datasetName" text,
    ...
)
```

I would strongly suggest fixing your schema. Quoted identifiers add no value in general, while on the other hand they make things unnecessary complicated. Camel case does not fill well for database identifiers, snake case is better, since case is not meaningful:

```
create table orders (
    ...,
    dataset_name text,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Snake case for the win. No capitals, no spaces. It is a huge annoyance to have to quote everything while writing DB code.